# How to use response.set_cookie in service object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I have method create in my `SigninController`:

```rb
def create
    user = User.find_by!(email: params[:email])
    if user.authenticate(params[:password])
      payload = { user_id: user.id }
      session = JWTSessions::Session.new(payload: payload, refresh_by_access_allowed: true)
      tokens = session.login
      response.set_cookie(JWTSessions.access_cookie,
                        value: tokens[:access],
                        httponly: true,
                        secure: Rails.env.production?)
      render json: { csrf: tokens[:csrf] }
    else
      not_authorized
    end
  end
```

How can i transfer this method to ServiceObject? When I copied this code to SignInService i got a

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `response' Did you mean respond_to?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set cookies in service objects. They should not depend on the transport method that is used by the client (HTTP in this case). You can return data from a service object and then use that data to set a cookie in a controller.